# Can you query the test suites from a cc_test?

Tags: bazel, build-tools

Is there a way to query the individual tests or the test suites from a `cc_test` rule? I know Bazel has the functionality to query the tests of a `test_suite` rule as such: `bazel query 'tests(//foo:smoke_tests)'` but I was wondering if there's an alternative for rules like `cc_test`.

If you are using Google Tests, you can pass `--gtest_list_tests` to the `--test_arg` command but that actually involves running `bazel test` and I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Not within the `cc_test`. But you could have a `genrule()` that calls the `cc_test` with `--gtest_list_tests` to dump all tests into a textfile. Or one level above a https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#genquery to list all test targets and dump them into a file. Those generated files can be consumed by something else.